# Grid with drag handles?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

How can i make grid to behave like a window? I mean when you drag the borders you can increase or decrease the grid's height and width.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve here, but maybe if you to put your grid within another one and on the parent Grid, use a GridSplitter to resize the Child Grid.  Here is a great example on how to use gridSplitters :

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-GridSplitter-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx

Comment: GridSplitter is not the thing which will help me. Basically i am creating a image cropping plugin and there is one image on top of which i want to show my grid and the user can drag the handles to resize the grid from the corners much like what we see in regular window.